# Can I turn Sky texture node into an hdri sequence?

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine, lighting, hdri

I have a scene where I need to animate the sun, in a timelapse kind of fashion, just going down past the horizon and coming out of the other side, all in a few seconds.

I think the easiest and most realistic way to do this is to use Nishita sky texture, but in the middle of production, I was forced to switch from Cycles to EEVEE because I stumbled onto a bunch of problems and I lacked the time to figure them out.

Problem is, the sky texture node doesn´t work in EEVEE, so I would need to export the animated texture on cycles, lighting included, to an image sequence or video, and then reimport it as an hdri. How can I pull this off?

Comment: Okay, I "solved" it and now I feel super stupid. One google search and I found a tutorial on how to do exactly this, from the one and only Ducky3d. In case anyone is interested, it´s over here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6u7MYVmkwyE
Man I suck at this xD

Comment: If you add a brief description of what things you have corrected you can and how to do it right you can post this as an answer instead of marking this question as "solved" in the title. If this link to the video goes offline this question has no value for future readers.